# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/ Is not working

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, apache-directory

I'm trying to redirect and entire wordpress site to a new domain EXCEPT one blog post, and the admin pages.

I've searched this site multiple times for various fixes, and across google searches. nothing has worked yet.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog-post-I-want-to-stay-on-old-domain/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/wp-login.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/wp-admin/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

I expected to be redirected with a full URL to a new domain, so oldsite.com/blog-post-1 would redirect to newsite.com/blog-post-1.

This works.

I expected the /wp-admin/ and the wp-login.php sections of the site to stay active without a redirect so I can continue editing the site if needed.

This works.

I expected oldsite.com/blog-post-I-want-to-stay-on-old-domain/ to **not** redirect, and be ignored, according to the ReWriteCond.

**This does not work.**

Instead it redirects to newsite.com/index.php and then newsite.com/

What have I done wrong?

Comment: I can’t spot anything wrong with this at first glance. Browsers tend to cache 301 redirects heavily, so if you added this exception later on, you might be tricked by your browser cache? Try to clear the history or test this in a new private window - any change?

Comment: no change at all :(

Comment: Are you sure the slug is 100% correct? You mentioned examples such as `oldsite.com/blog-post-1`, so does the request for this particular blog post actually have a trailing slash?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !wp-login|wp-admin|blog-post-I-want-to-stay-on-old-domain
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't even remember asking this question 3 years ago but I hope it helps the next person to stumble upon this topic. Thank you!